# how to create a tar file with checksums, but without compression

Tags: linux, tar, archive, socat

(note, this is not a duplicate of [Creating a tar file with checksums included](https://serverfault.com/questions/120582/creating-a-tar-file-with-checksums-included))

I'm familiar with using tar + gzip to create a compressed tar file (`tar cf - files | gzip > something.tar.gz`), and gzip does add a master checksum so it will be apparent if the file gets corrupted.  This is nearly the behaviour I want.

However, I have a computer with a (really) slow processor, but a fast network card.  I've found that if I use tar plus gzip plus socat, that my network transfer is 1/10th the speed (100Mbps) versus leaving the gzip command out of the pipeline (950Mbps).

Some archive utilities, like 7Zip and Zip support an option for zero compression.  I don't see that gzip or bzip2 have such an option.  But Zip and 7Zip don't support proper streaming like gzip and bzip2 do (I know that 7z can read/write the plaintext from stdio, but it won't write the compressed file to stdout).  I must have a proper streaming "compression" program because I'll be using socat to ship the archive to a remote host.

So the question is, is there a way to create a tar archive, while wrapping the output in a archive-like format, not using gzip or bzip2?  Or is there some way to tickle gzip or bzip2 into using "no compression"?  Or is there a dirt-simple ultra-fast streaming compression utility which might use only RLE encoding?

caveats - it needs to be fully streaming so I can use socat; the solution must be CPU light; solution must use parts available in cygwin and debian repositories

Comment: Gzip supports variable levels of compression, with corresponding demands on processor usage.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452429/does-gzip-compression-level-have-any-impact-on-decompression)

Comment: gzip at its fastest (using -1 arg) is still intolerably slow.  That's why I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lz4` as a drop-in replacement for gzip. The compression rate is not as good, but it is usually blazing-fast compared to gzip.

It may still be too slow for what you're trying to do, but it is probably worth a look.

You can also `tee` the output of `tar` into two different streams and push one of them into `md5sum`, `sha1sum` or `sha256sum` by calling
`tar cf - files | tee >(md5sum) | whatever-command`.

Comment: The LZ4 idea looks to be a viable solution.  It's not zero compression, but it is much much faster than gzip or bzip2.

Comment: If you add a -B4 argument to LZ4, it makes it faster, resulting in a 15% to 25% increase in network throughput (which is a good thing).